# jQuery: blur() is not working on dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery

Once Blur event is called, alert box should be displayed.
Blur event is working for default row, but not in dynamically added rows.
I even tried class selector also but didn't worked.

HTML:

```
<table  class="test">
     <tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" class="plusbtn" /></td>
     <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="minusbtn" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fname</th><th>Lname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' id="Fname" ></td>
    <td><input type='text' id="Lname"  ></td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Jquery:

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var markup = "<tr><td><input type='text' id='Fname' ></td><td><input type='text' id='Lname'></td></td></tr>";
          $('.plusbtn').click(function() {
            $(".test").append(markup);
        });
        $('.minusbtn').click(function() {
            if($(".test tr").length != 1)
                {
                    $(".test tr:last-child").remove();
                }
           else
                {
                    alert("You cannot delete first row");
                }
        });
        var $Fname=$("#Fname");
        var $Lname=$("#Lname");

        $('#Fname').on('blur',function(){

            alert($Fname.val())
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am unable to solve the issue.Please make suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler for elements you append to the DOM after load. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information. Also be aware that you're duplicating `id` attributes when the HTML gets appended - you should change the `id` to `class` for the `input` elements

Comment: Try this one is working fine : $("table").on("blur", "#Fname", function(){
            alert('hello');
 });

Answer (score 2):

You have same ID on every lick, this will not work.

Also you are binding event to dynamic element wrong:

```
$(static_element).on('event', 'dynamic_element', function)

$(document).on('blur', '.Fname', function () {});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, blur is working, but how to add "this" function to that alert.